# How to work with DATETIME in MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0?

Tags: c++, mysql-8.0

I'm using mysql-connector-cpp-8.0.18(https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp)

Mysql result stores is variable with type mysqlx::Value https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/classmysqlx_1_1abi2_1_1r0_1_1_value.html

```
/*
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_update` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
*/


RowResult res = mysession.sql("SELECT id, data_update FROM table_name").execute();

Row row;
while ((row = res.fetchOne())) {
  cout << "Id: " << row[0] << endl; // Ok
  std::string data_update = row[1]; // How to get datetime here?
  // row[1].getType() == Type::Document(8)
}
```

How should I work with DATETIME?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [mysql forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,683855,683912#msg-683912)

The solution is parsing raw data. It use [protobuf base 128 variant](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints)

Simple example for decoding:

```
uint64_t DecodeOne(uint8_t * in , size_t * len) {
  uint64_t r = 0;

  do {
    uint64_t val = * in ;
    r = (r << 7) | (uint64_t)(val & 127); in ++;
    ( * len) --;
  } while (( * len > 0) && (uint64_t( * in ) & 128));

  return r;
}

void DecodeBuffer(uint8_t * buffer, size_t size) {
  std::vector < uint8_t > reverseBuffer;
  for (size_t i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    reverseBuffer.push_back(buffer[size - i]);
  }

  size_t tmpSize = size;
  uint8_t * reverseData = reverseBuffer.data();

  while (tmpSize > 0) {
    std::cout << DecodeOne( & reverseData[size - tmpSize], & tmpSize) << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}

mysqlx_get_bytes(row, idx, 0, data, size);
DecodeBuffer(data, size);

std::pair <
  const unsigned char * , size_t > res = value.getRawBytes();
DecodeBuffer(res.first, res.second);
```

But there is [a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98452) in CPP API in mysql-connector-cpp-8.0.18.

CPP result doesnot contain seconds. So its possible to use only c api.

Comment: That bug was fixed in 8.0.20 (released 2020-04-27)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-cpp/en/news-8-0-20.html